# django HttpResponse Location redirect

Tags: python, django

I am trying to redirect to another page when http response is `True` I have added `response['Location'] = 'login.html'` but it's not working, I am getting a page with `True` written but not the login page. Can you help me I am new to django.

I have written this code

```
if user_obj:
    response = HttpResponse(True)
    response['Location'] = 'login.html'
    return response
else:
    return HttpResponse(False)
```

Comment: That is because the status code is not in the 300-399 range.

Answer (score 1):

from django.urls import reverse

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('url_name'))

Answer (score 1):

This will not work because you do not use a response in the 300-399 range, which are used for redirection, for example the [*HTTP 302 Found* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302). You furthermore do *not* need to do this yourself, you can make use of Django's [**`HttpResponseRedirect(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect):

```
if user_obj:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('login.html')

else:
    return HttpResponse(False)
```

You can also specify content, but normally if the browser makes the redirect, this will not show up for long:

```
if user_obj:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('login.html', content='True')

else:
    return HttpResponse(False)
```

Using `.html` however is (at least by Django) considered "ugly". It is also better to make use of `reverse`, or `redirect` to resolve the URL for a given view.

Comment: I am sending True to ajax post but with your answer how can I achieve this?

Comment: @RahulRaj: well an AJAX request will not care about the redirect, so then you will need to do the redirect yourself at the JavaScript layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use Django core [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) function.

```
if user_obj:
    // Do something
    return redirect('some_url')
```